# Need help understanding a .sort_by block within my Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to improve my coding by working through Code Wars problems and am doing it in a specific manner. First I try working out the code on my own. Failing that I do a few Google searches (Stack Exchange) to troubleshoot. Failing that I unlock the answer to the problem and then thoroughly examine it and articulate the code in writing so I understand the code within the answer. Well, I had to the the latter today.

I understand the lion's share of the code, but I am feeling a bit shaky around my understanding of the code in the *fourth line*. I have done a bunch of research around the methods used in this code on Rubydocs, but still feel in the dark. Could someone please articulate it part for part for me? I am also looking for any type of advice around my current articulation of the code.

---

```
def letter_frequency(text)
  chars = text.downcase.scan(/[a-zA-Z]/).sort
  chars.map { |x| [x, chars.count(x)] }.uniq
  .sort_by { |y| [-y[1], y[0]] }
end
```

1. *set the "chars" variable to text (the parameter), lowercased, 
   scan and return any single charecter between the range a-z or A-Z, and 
   then sort them lowest to high.*
2. *use **.map** to set a key variable and return all of the charecters 
   inside the submitted array with the total count for the key (x),
   and then make all charecteds unique with the .uniq method.*
3. *Then sort with the given block using the "y" key to return all 
   of the negative/positive numbers  and their count within the submitted 
   array.*

---

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort_by` does pretty much what it sounds like. It lets you "sort" a hash based on some criteria (that you pass to a block). Since hashes don't really have an order, it returns an array sorted by the criteria you passed in the block:

Consider the following hash (count of the characters in 'hello'):

`chars = {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1}`

The key is the character and the value is the count. If we wanted a sorted array of characters based on their count, we could run `sort_by` on the above hash based on the value like so:

`chars.sort_by { |key, value| value }`

That would return the following:

`[["h", 1], ["e", 1], ["o", 1], ["l", 2]]`

If we wanted the most common characters first, we'd sort on `-value`:

`chars.sort_by { |key, value| -value }`

Which would return the following:

`[["l", 2], ["h", 1], ["e", 1], ["o", 1]]`

I've rewritten your method with some tweaks:

```
def letter_frequency(text)
  count = Hash.new 0
  chars = text.downcase.scan(/[a-zA-Z]/)
  chars.each do |char|
    count[char] += 1
  end
  count.sort_by { |_, value| -value }
end
```

First, `count` is the hash that stores the counts of the characters of your text, which we then sort by the count of each character (`value`).  The `_` in the `sort_by` block is a bit of shorthand because we don't use the key of the hash for anything.

Comment: Your method implementation differs in behaviour from the original; it doesn't do an alphabetical inner-sort.